# Routing to different servers with nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to use nginx as a router while keeping the requested domain in the URL? For example, if I hit mysite.com, the nginx routing server looks at the URL and directs traffic to a particular server, all while maintaining the original requested domain in the URL.

E.g.

```
mysite.com/site1/params
Router -> site1.mysite.com/params
```

But even though behind the scenes `site1.mysite.com/params` is being called, the user sees `mysite.com/site1/params` in the URL.

I've taken a stab at the configuration, but seem to be getting 404's.

```
upstream site1 {
  server site1.mysite.com;
}

location /site1 {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass  http://site1;
  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use location with trailing slash, remove rewrite and use `proxy_pass` with `/` uri. Nginx will take of replacing `/site1/` with `/`. Also, you may need to set `Host` header to `site1.mysite.com` not the `$host`.

```
location /site1/ {
  proxy_pass  http://site1/;
  proxy_set_header Host site1.mysite.com;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to redirect me to mysite.com:random-port

Comment: Just in addition to my last comment, it works if I manually type in port 80 to the initial URL, is there any way to get around that?

Comment: You should put port to upstream definition `server site1.mysite.com:80;`

Comment: Yeah, same issue when I try that : /. Perhaps it's cached.

Comment: Oops. Port 80 is default. Try to clear browser cache

Comment: That worked! One last quick question, how can I make sure that params get passed in as well? Would that be in the `proxy_pass`?

Comment: They are proxied by default.